# datetime pickers2

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in programming. My question relates to using datetime pickers. I used the folderbrowserdialog in my program to access a number of files from a folder and then manipulated them to derive various outputs such as mean, minimum and maximum values etc. I then included datatime pickers and the folderbrowserdialog button in order to perform tasks on files for specific time periods. However, when the code runs, it request that I specify the location of the folder. The program then generates the required output, without requesting for the time interval for which I need the output for. How can I get the program to ask me to select the time interval after the selection of the folder that contains the csv files.  The code is below:

```
namespace Filereader_m_15062012
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
            // create a list to insert the data into
            //put all the files in the root directory into array
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath, "*.csv");

            // Display all files.
            TextWriter tw1 = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/a3708906/Documents/Filereader m 26062012 -2/Filereader m 22062012/listoffiles.txt");

            List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
            tw1.WriteLine("--- Files: ---");
            foreach (string path in fileEntries)
            {
                tw1.WriteLine(path);
            }

            tw1.Close();

            //int count = 0;
            //float sum = 0;

            string fileID1 =""; 
            List<string> fileID   = new List<string>();
            List<string> means = new List<string>();
            List<string> maximums = new List<string>();
            List<string> minimums = new List<string>();


            TextWriter tw2 = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/a3708906/Documents/Filereader m 26062012 -2/Filereader m 22062012/errorlist.txt");
            foreach (string path in fileEntries)
            {
                if (File.Exists(path))
                {  
                    string text = "";
                    // create a list to insert the data into
                    List<float> noise = new List<float>();
                    List<DateTime> time = new List<DateTime>();

                    TextWriter tw3 = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/a3708906/Documents/Filereader m 26062012 -2/Filereader m 22062012/rawdata.txt");

                    string file = path;

                    FileInfo src = new FileInfo(file);
                    TextReader reader = src.OpenText();
                    text = reader.ReadLine();

                    // while the text being read in from reader.Readline() is not null
                    while (text != null)
                    {
                        text = reader.ReadLine();

                        {
                            while (text != null)
                            {
                                text = reader.ReadLine();
                                if (text != null)
                                {
                                    string[] words = text.Split(',');
                                    noise.Add(Convert.ToSingle(words[3]));
                                    time.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(words[2]));
                                    fileID1 = words[1];

                                    // write text to a file
                                    tw3.WriteLine(text);
                                    //foreach (string word in words)
                                    //{
                                    //    tw.WriteLine(word);
                                    //}
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        tw3.Close();

                        TextWriter tw4 = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/a3708906/Documents/Filereader m 26062012 -2/Filereader m 22062012/noise.txt");

                        //float minValue = noise.Min();
                        float maxValue = Enumerable.Max(noise);
                        float mean = Enumerable.Average(noise); 
                        float minValue = Enumerable.Min(noise);
                        //float maxValue = noise.Max();
                        //float mean = noise.Average(); 

                        //foreach (float ns in noise)
                        {
                            //tw4.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(ns));
                            //count++;
                            //sum += ns;
                            //mean = sum / count; 

                            //float min1 = 0; 
                            //if (ns > max) 
                                //max = ns; 
                            //else if (ns < max) 
                                //min1 = ns; 
                            //if (min1 < min && min1 > 0) 
                            //min = min1; 
                        }

                        tw4.Close();

                        fileID.Add(Convert.ToString(fileID1)); 
                        means.Add(Convert.ToString(mean));
                        maximums.Add(Convert.ToString(maxValue));
                        minimums.Add(Convert.ToString(minValue));
                    }                            
                }

                else
                {
                    tw2.WriteLine("{0}", path);
                }

                tw2.Close();
            }

            TextWriter tw5 = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/a3708906/Documents/Filereader m 26062012 -2/Filereader m 22062012/IDs.txt");
            tw5.WriteLine("FILE IDS");
            tw5.WriteLine("==========");
            foreach (string m in fileID)
            {
                tw5.WriteLine("MOTE {0}", (m));
            }

            tw5.Close();


            TextWriter tw6 = new StreamWriter("C:/Users/a3708906/Documents/Filereader m 26062012 -2/Filereader m 22062012/results.txt");
            tw6.WriteLine("File IDs" + "          " + "Means" + "          " + "Maximums" + "        " +  "Minimums");
            tw6.WriteLine("========" + "          " + "=====" + "          " + "========" + "        " +  "========");
            for (int i=0; i < fileID.Count; i++)
                   {
                       int j = i;
                       tw6.WriteLine("Mote" + " " + Convert.ToString(fileID[i]) + "          " + Convert.ToString(means[j]) + "          " + Convert.ToString(maximums[j]) + "              " + Convert.ToString(minimums[j]));         
                    }

            tw6.Close();

        }       


        private void folderBrowserDialog1_HelpRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
```

I wil be grateful for anybody's help with this. Thanks.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the parts that are necessary for answering your question. No one really likes reading a wall of text/code before even remotely knowing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

try making another form with the two date time pickers

the form2 should look like this

label saying start

datetimepicker start

label saying end

datetimepicker end

button ok

the code for it should be something like this:

```
 private void btok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dtpickerend.Value == dtpickerstart.Value)
            MessageBox.Show("Please select an interval", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        else
        {
            Program.date_start = dtpickerstart.Value;
            Program.date_end = dtpickerend.Value;
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
            this.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
```

also go to program.cs and add these two variables

```
/// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime date_start;
    public static DateTime date_end;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
```

and finally in your main form when you want call that form add these:

```
secondform datepicker_dialog = new secondform();
        DialogResult dr;
        dr = datepicker_dialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
            //means that the user succseful selected an interval
            ;
        else
            //means the user closed the second form
            ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're doing everything in the `Load` event handler, which is invoked right away when the form is being loaded, so you don't have the time to set the two DateTimePickers.

Add a button to the form, then move everything to its `Click` event handler. Of course you'll have to change your code so that it takes into account the value set in both of the DateTimePickers, which you can access via their `Value` property.

It's not clear what you need two dates for, but in case you want to only consider files based on their creation/last modification/last access date, you can import the `System.IO` namespace and use the relevant methods and properties from the `Directory`, `File` and `FileInfo` class.